# safari con't connect to localhost Xampp in Mac

Tags: mysql, apache, server, localhost, hosts

I downloaded Xampp in my Mac for first time, the server is working but when I want to go to my application show that safari can not connect to server.
does any one know where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have the latest version of XAMPP.

You can reach your application by clicking on the button "Go to Application" or writing your IP address showed in XAMPP followed by "/dashboard/" or your browser (e.g 192.168.64.2/dashboard like the image shows)

[general tab xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Iq7o.png)

If you have already tried this, the problem might be related to the network configuration in XAMPP.
Create a new rule that forward the LocalPort 80 to the RemotePort 80, and check the "Require Local" checkbox.
After that, enable the rule and test it using "localhost/dashboard/" in your browser.

[network tab xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxJC4.png)

Comment: yes I have the last version ,I tried both of them but it still not working

Comment: My bad, the second try would be "localhost/dashboard/" again. I'll update the answer